# SQL Query to Replace Multiple Matching Rows With a New Row

Tags: sql, postgresql

For simplicity, suppose I have a SQL table with one column, containing numeric data. Sample data is

```
11
13
21
22
23
3
31
32
33
41
42
131
132
133
141
142
143
```

If the table contains ALL the numbers of the form x1, x2, x3, but NOT x (where x is all of the digits of a number but the last digit. So for 123456, x would be 12345),  then I want to replace these three rows with a new row, x.

The desired output of the above data would be:

```
11
13
2
3
31
32
33
41
42
131
132
133
14
```

How would I accomplish this with SQL? I should mention that I do not want to permanently alter the data - just for the query results.
Thanks.

Comment: @Magnus Yes. The numbers to combine need to be greater than 10. Thanks for pointing out that additional restriction.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? There are helpful features available for some databases.

Comment: What should the result of (11,12,13,111,112,113) be? (1,11) or (1,111,112,113)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Good question. I guess it depends on the query order. It could be either after one run. If run twice, it would be (1, 11).

Comment: @brian_d: the question is: what **should** it be? In the case of (1,11), you need a procedure.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It should be (1,11) then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume

- the presence of to functions: `lastDigit` and `head` producing the last digit and the rest of the input value respectively
- the data is unique
- only the digits 1,2,3 are used for constructing the table values
- the table is named `t` and has a single column `x`
- you don't want this to work recursively
- create a view `n` like this: `select head(x) h, lastDigit(x) last from t` You can use inline views instead
- create a view c like this

  select h
  from n
  group by h
  having count(*) = 3

Then this should give the desired result:

```
select distinct x 
from (
    select x from t where head(x) not in (select h from c)
    union
    select h from c
)
```

Comment: Works, thanks! One fix in your pseudocode is that `select h` should be `select head`

Comment: fixed it (the other way round)

Comment: Full solution would have to be recursive or procedural (see comments on question). Still +1 for a very nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need two SQL commands, one to remove the existing rows and the second to add the new row.  They would look like this (where `:X` is a parameter containing your base number, 14 in your example):

```
 DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn BETWEEN (:X*10) AND ((:X*10) + 9)

 INSERT INTO YourTable (YourColumn) VALUES (:X)
```

Note: I assume you want all the numbers from x0 to x9 to be removed, so that's what I wrote above.  If you really only want x1, x2, x3 removed, then you would use this `DELETE` statement instead:

```
 DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn BETWEEN ((:X*10) + 1) AND ((:X*10) + 3)
```

Comment: your assumption about the values being 0-9 is correct. However in your solution, you delete all values between a range, regardless if the range is not full (correct me if I am wrong). I would not want to replace an incomplete range, such as 140, 141, 142, 149 with 14.

Comment: I was not clear on needing the full range to match, I have adjusted my question.

Comment: No, I completely missed that requirement.  Is this column declared UNIQUE (that is, no repeating values)?

Comment: Yes. (Well in the real table the column does repeat, but combined with a second column it is UNIQUE)